# how to copy the source src to folder using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

my html file

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="SUBMIT" id="btsubmit" onclick="getsrc()">
```

my script

I took the source path

```
<form id="f1" name="form1" method="post">

    var imagesrc = document.getElementById("ClonedElementX").src;

</form>
```

my ajax code

```
 i need to copy the source path to targeted path using ajax 

       $('#btsubmit').change(function() {
            $(imagesrc).ajaxForm({ target: "C:\Users\Bhargavi\workspace\HTML\storedimage" }).submit();
            return false;
        });
```

I am new to ajax please help me what i did wrong in this

Comment: should'nt you be passing your form id in the ajax form rather than the $(imagesrc)..???

Comment: are u trying to upload image file through this ajax form..??

Comment: ya i am trying to upload the image using ajax

Answer (score 0):

I have'nt checked this.But something like this might do it for you... :)

html

```
<div id='preview'></div>
    <form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php'>
    <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
     </form>
```

Script File

```
$('#photoimg').live('change', function() 
 {
      $("#imageform").ajaxForm({target: '#preview', //Shows the response image in the div named preview 
         success:function(){

         }, 
         error:function(){

          } 
       }).submit();
});
```

ajaximage.php

```
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
$name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];
$tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
$path = "uploads/";
move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$name) //Stores the image in the uploads folder
}
```

Comment: i am the beginner of ajax i didn't use php

Comment: Sorry,If you don't use php,how do you suppose to upload the image file into your system..???u can't simple give the location that you wish to save in the "target" part of the ajaxform.You can't do that...

Comment: tell me how to upload image to the folder using ajax

Comment: Thats what i have answered above.U have to be using php inorder to upload the file..

Comment: we can use html also know?