# uploading image using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm stuck!! :(
I want to upload image file with a title and a caption, I want to use javascript for validation of title caption and a file choosen.

My html goes here:

```
<input type="text" name="title2" id="title2" value="title" /><br />

<textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="caption" >caption goes here...</textarea><br />
<input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" /><br />
<button id="submit_info" onclick="photowcap()" >post</button><br />
```

and my javascript here:

```
function photowcap()
{

var title = document.getElementsByName("title2")[0].value;
var photo = document.getElementsByName("photo")[0].value;
var captions = document.getElementsByName("caption")[0].value;
var caption = encodeURIComponent(captions)

var xmlhttp;
if(title == "" || title == " " || title == "title")
{
    document.getElementsByName("title2")[0].focus();
    document.getElementsByName("title2")[0].value="";
    return;
}
else if(captions == "" || captions == " " || captions == "caption goes here..."){
    document.getElementsByName("caption")[0].focus();
    document.getElementsByName("caption")[0].value="";
    return;
}
else if(photo == ""){
    alert("please choose image");
}
else{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            alert("Success!!!");
        }
    }
xmlhttp.open("GET","photowcap.php?    title="+title+"&caption="+caption+"&photo="+photo,true);
    xmlhttp.send();}

}
```

And for saving it using php:

```
<?php

include("admin_conn.php");

$title = $_GET["title"];
$caption = $_GET["caption"];
$photo = $_GET["photo"];
$time=time();
$date = (date("D F d Y",$time));

$query_photowcap = "INSERT INTO school_updates(title, photo, caption, date, time)     VALUES('$title','$photo','$caption','$date','$time')";
mysql_query($query_photowcap);

?>
```

it only save for the file path as "C:fakepath/filename...." because I dont have any idea on how to get filename using javascript, and finally I have this code for saving the actual image into the folder but I dont really get where I should place it: THANKS IN ADVANCE :)

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
$max_file_size = 200 * 1024; #200kb
if (($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/gif")
  || ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
  || ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/png" )
  && ($_FILES["photo"]["size"] < $max_file_size))
  {
  $path = 'images/' . uniqid();
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],
  $path.$_FILES["photo"]["name"]);

  }
else
  {
  echo "Files must be either JPEG, GIF, or PNG and less than 200 kb";
  }

?>
```

Comment: "C:fakepath/filename...." is sth given by the browser security settings. The original path you won't be able to get. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/file-upload.html was done by professional programmers, and even they couldn't circumvent it.

Comment: please help :) I'm just kinda stucked...sorry for bad english :D

Comment: Help with WHAT EXACTLY?

Comment: @Alexdn you need to learn how files work. This is not as simple as copy/paste. You need to send the file as binary data and handle it as such on the server side.

Comment: I have done uploading image before, but using pure PHP. Now, I want to do it with javascript. What can you suggest sir??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to access files with the `$_FILES` superglobal they need to be sent with a `multipart/form-data` content-type header and appropriate attributes. Unfortunately you cannot do this with `xhr`'s send method manually because sending a string will be automatically converted to `UTF-8`. Fortunately though you can still send binary data such as a file from javascript's `window.File`.

This is not supported in older browsers. The code would look like

```
var file = document.getElementById('photo').files[0];

...

xhr.send(file);
```

And then on the server side you will need to access the input buffer directly in order to grab a hold of this file

```
$file = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

If you insist on using `$_FILES` you could use the `FormData` object in javascript. The reason I left this as a second option is because I've heard about greater support issues and I personally avoid using it for now.

```
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('theForm'));
...
xhr.send(formData);
```

## EDIT 2016

It has been some time now since I posted this answer and now the FormData object is widely supported, if you are looking to upload files along with other data you may look into that.

Comment: Didn't know this... can you share a link or something with more details?

Comment: @zozo Have a look at the File API and XHR2.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to upload an image with ajax... short answer... normally you can't. You need a multipart/form-data to upload, making ajax upload a pain.

An easy work around would be to validate the form with js, then normally submit it. Like here: [Ajax Upload image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447435/ajax-upload-image) - well... ignore the title, is misleading.

Comment: Now, I have just realized something important.

Comment: You can share with the rest... not just make us curious :).

Comment: You can upload files via ajax in all modern browsers.

Comment: That's why I said normally... and said it is a pain not impossible :P. Also ty for the other comment (at php_nub) answer.

Comment: It's not a pain, it's very easy with the File API and XHR2

Comment: You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications