# Ajax pic upload using code

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have `input` elements in my html page. When user presses the submit button, it being binded to the `click` even in jquery and the data is being validated and then send to server using AJAX. The problem is, I have a `file` field. So how to initiate the uploading of the file via the code using AJAX ?

Sample code:

```
$(function(){
  $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function(){
    // validate fields, make some processing on the data, etc.
    // then send to server using AJAX...

    $.ajax({
      //.... 
    });

    // after submitting the above data or along with it, I want the picture uploaded(without user having to press upload button or anything)
  });
});
```

How it can be done?

Comment: My suggestion would be to google "ajax file upload" there are a few good plugins out there designed to do exactly this

Comment: Yes I have looked at some of the jQuery plugins. But the examples mentioned are like it will upload the file right after we select the image. What I want is, the uploading to be initiated via code. Because I had to do other processing on the user inputted data(some texts, dropdowns, etc) before sending to server!

Comment: try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447435/ajax-upload-image