# form submission with image upload using jquery ajax in laravel5

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i am trying to submit a form with image upload using jquery ajax, but each time i select an image and click on submit button alert($(this).serialize()) shows-

_token=TCWpR3n9Uf2FpKMXi639Dcvzhc7t4fVDWDopjZ8V .

here is my form -

```
{!! Form::open(['action'=>'ImageController@store', 'name'=>'form1', 'id'=>'formId1', 'files'=>true]) !!}

<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::file('image') !!}                         
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::submit('Upload', array( 'class'=>'btn btn-danger', 'name'=>'image_form_submit'  )) !!}                        
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

here the js-

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("form").submit(function(e){ //
           e.preventDefault();


        alert($(this).serialize()); //always alerts the tocken- _token=TCWpR3n9Uf2FpKMXi639Dcvzhc7t4fVDWDopjZ8V 
        $.ajax({

            type:"POST",
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data){

            }
        })
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

i want to get the serialized data of form and post via ajax to my controller.
why alert always shows  the token?

Comment: So what data should you get on form serialize?

Comment: Here in your code their is no form element then token. If you want to upload img then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447435/ajax-upload-image?answertab=active#tab-top    this should be the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of ajax image uploading "$(this).serialize()" didn't work.

You have to pass (data:formData,) as below -

```
 $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data:formData,
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data){

        }
    })
```

Comment: yes, this works! but how to retrieve value of formData in laravel controller?

Comment: this will pass value same as serialize() passes ,you can see the output using method

Input::all();