# how to submit multipart form using jquery ajax without formajax plugin and don't want to use hidden iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I found some solution to it using jquery plugin formajax, did well in computers and laptop but got problem in ipad, tablet , mobiles. Is there is anyway to do so, currently i am doing like this

```
$(document).on('submit','#mulitpartform',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#multipartform').ajaxSubmit({
       'method'    :    "url",
       beforeSend  :    function(){
                         //overlay
                        },
       success     :    function(responseText)
                        {
                          // stuffs
                         },
       error       :     function()
                         {

                         },
       complete    :     function()
                         {
                           //trunoff overlay
                         } 
    });
});
```

it works fine in laptop,computers but experience problem in mobile devices; what should i do to get out of it.

Comment: kiran ji i tried it to but didn't work

Comment: What did you try and what was the result? Can you describe a bit more?

Comment: no error as  $('#multipartform').ajaxSubmit(); but somehow it couldnot send file to backend, while i try to read Input::file("file_name"); function of laravel it returns empty value; when i comment e.preventDefault () it works; the problem occurs only in mobile devices but works fine in desktop; I use chrome inspector to inspect mobile chrome didnot show any error around it.

Comment: It seems you are trying to upload file using ajax. For same purpose I would like to refer link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447435/ajax-upload-image

Comment: yes this works fine thanks

Comment: Kiran ji I think you are too good at front-end programming ... can you specify some links that help to show the upload progress bar; backend is php

Comment: Try https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/. It is one of the best ajax uploader solution.