# AJAX Image Upload with React, Rails and Paperclip

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs

Been searching but nothing comes close to my question, except [this php question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447435/ajax-upload-image).

In my react component, using Rails 5, I could upload an image to S3 only if I **submit** the form; I don't want to refresh the page so I thought I could simply use ajax for that:

```
...

imageUpload(){
  var formData = $(this).serialize();
   $.ajax({
       url: '<url>',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       async: false,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success: function (data) {
           console.log(data);
       },
       error: function () {
           alert("error in ajax form submission");
       }
   });
},

...
```

**The html:**

```
<form encType="multipart/form-data" acceptCharset="UTF-8">
  <input
    type="file"
    name="user[evidence]"
    id="user_evidence"
  />
  <button className="success button small" onClick={this.imageUpload}>Upload</button>
</form>
```

The goes to the update method (ajax url finds the method no problem):

```
...

def update
 u = User.find(1)
 u.update_attributes(user_evidence) # causing ajax to return an error
end

private
  def user_evidence
   params.require(:user).permit(:evidence)
  end
```

When an image is added and button is clicked, nothing uploads to s3. I guess I'm missing some sort of *remote* information with the ajax?

**EDIT:**

I have created a simple rails 5 app with this issue [here](https://github.com/SylarRuby/react_ajax_upload).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `this` inside your method to reference the form.
Try using [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html).

```
<form ref="myForm" ...>
...
var formData = $(this.refs.myForm).serialize();
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that but getting an error with the `update` method. See updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<form remote="true"...>
```

Comment: Hi. I'll let you know in a few weeks time as I'm restarting the project from scratch.

Comment: I have updated my post with a simple app demonstrating the same issue.