# Image upload with data in asp classic

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I am working on asp classic. I have three fields
**First Name**
**Last Name**
**Upload Image**
I want to post data with ajax request to .asp page and want to retrieve values on .asp page. 
I have post request like this:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    data:
                    {
                        'method':'EOTMInsert',
                        'fname':Fname,
                        'lname':Lname
                    },
                    url:"/async2.asp",
                    dataType:"text",
                    success:function(data, status) {
                        httpResults = data;
                        alert("Employee saved.");
                        jQuery(location).attr('href','/eotm.asp');
                    },
                    async:false
                });
```

Values retrieved on .asp form

```
set fname = Request("fname")
        set lname = Request("lname")
```

Now, I also want to post image and want to save on root path.

If have any idea please share with me.
Thanks

Comment: what you have tried so for? with out your code how can we help?

Comment: I have edited the request, please go through the detail once.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447435/ajax-upload-image

Comment: @Dinesh this answer is related to `php` language, not `asp`

Comment: @RicardoPontual he wants to upload file using ajax with some input thats why i gave that link. he has problem client side not server side

Comment: @Dinesh I understand and it's a good link, but since it's not same problem, due to the platform difference, you can suggest the link, but not say it's duplicate

Comment: Thanks @Dinesh and @Ricardo, i have fixed this problem using below code and used `clsUpload` class for image and retrieve field values at server side.  `$('#customerFirstForm').bind('submit',(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var formData = new FormData(this);
     $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      data:formData,
      cache:false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success:function(data){
     console.log("Success");
      },
      error: function(data){
       console.log("error");
      }
     });
    }));`

Comment: @GurpreetSingh congrats. you found your answer