# Ajax is not sending the image

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, image-uploading, laravel-5.8

i'm submitting a form in which some of inputs and a input of image and sending it through ajax FormData all the text data is properly submit and in controller i can see it using dd() but no data is showing for image

```
var formdata= new FormData($(".com_form")[0]);


                        formdata.append('com-name',com_name);

                    //$("#emp-com-form").trigger("reset");

                    $.ajax({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        },
                    url:'/company-registration',
                    type:'POST',
                    data:formdata,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    dataType:'JSON',
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',

                    success:function(data){
                    //window.location.href= 'next-step.html?type='+type;
                    //window.location.href= '/login';
                        console.log(data);

                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                    console.log('Error:', data);
                    }
                    });
                    });
```

this is the ajax code

```
 public function companyReg(Request $request){

       http_response_code(500);
        dd($request->all());

}
```

this is controller code

```
<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl', addEventListener = function (e, n, cb) { e.addEventListener(n, cb, false); }; (doc.documentElement.firstElementChild || doc.documentElement.children[0]).appendChild(refStyle); if (!doc.addEventListener) { addEventListener = function (element, eventName, callback) { element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function (e) { e.preventDefault = function () {e.returnValue = false;}; e.target = e.srcElement; callback(e); }); }; } function toggle(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className, arrow, newClass; if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(oldClass)) { arrow = '&#9660;'; newClass = 'sf-dump-expanded'; } else if (/\bsf-dump-expanded\b/.test(oldClass)) { arrow = '&#9654;'; newClass = 'sf-dump-compact'; } else { return false; } if (doc.createEvent && s.dispatchEvent) { var event = doc.createEvent('Event'); event.initEvent('sf-dump-expanded' === newClass ? 'sfbeforedumpexpand' : 'sfbeforedumpcollapse', true, false); s.dispatchEvent(event); } a.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; s.className = s.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-(compact|expanded)\b/, newClass); if (recursive) { try { a = s.querySelectorAll('.'+oldClass); for (s = 0; s < a.length; ++s) { if (-1 == a[s].className.indexOf(newClass)) { a[s].className = newClass; a[s].previousSibling.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; } } } catch (e) { } } return true; }; function collapse(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className; if (/\bsf-dump-expanded\b/.test(oldClass)) { toggle(a, recursive); return true; } return false; }; function expand(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className; if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(oldClass)) { toggle(a, recursive); return true; } return false; }; function collapseAll(root) { var a = root.querySelector('a.sf-dump-toggle'); if (a) { collapse(a, true); expand(a); return true; } return false; } function reveal(node) { var previous, parents = []; while ((node = node.parentNode || {}) && (previous = node.previousSibling) && 'A' === previous.tagName) { parents.push(previous); } if (0 !== parents.length) { parents.forEach(function (parent) { expand(parent); }); return true; } return false; } function highlight(root, activeNode, nodes) { resetHighlightedNodes(root); Array.from(nodes||[]).forEach(function (node) { if (!/\bsf-dump-highlight\b/.test(node.className)) { node.className = node.className + ' sf-dump-highlight'; } }); if (!/\bsf-dump-highlight-active\b/.test(activeNode.className)) { activeNode.className = activeNode.className + ' sf-dump-highlight-active'; } } function resetHighlightedNodes(root) { Array.from(root.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-str, .sf-dump-key, .sf-dump-public, .sf-dump-protected, .sf-dump-private')).forEach(function (strNode) { strNode.className = strNode.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-highlight\b/, ''); strNode.className = strNode.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-highlight-active\b/, ''); }); } return function (root, x) { root = doc.getElementById(root); var indentRx = new RegExp('^('+(root.getAttribute('data-indent-pad') || ' ').replace(rxEsc, '\\$1')+')+', 'm'), options = {"maxDepth":1,"maxStringLength":160,"fileLinkFormat":false}, elt = root.getElementsByTagName('A'), len = elt.length, i = 0, s, h, t = []; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); for (i in x) { options[i] = x[i]; } function a(e, f) { addEventListener(root, e, function (e, n) { if ('A' == e.target.tagName) { f(e.target, e); } else if ('A' == e.target.parentNode.tagName) { f(e.target.parentNode, e); } else if ((n = e.target.nextElementSibling) && 'A' == n.tagName) { if (!/\bsf-dump-toggle\b/.test(n.className)) { n = n.nextElementSibling; } f(n, e, true); } }); }; function isCtrlKey(e) { return e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey; } function xpathString(str) { var parts = str.match(/[^'"]+|['"]/g).map(function (part) { if ("'" == part) { return '"\'"'; } if ('"' == part) { return "'\"'"; } return "'" + part + "'"; }); return "concat(" + parts.join(",") + ", '')"; } function xpathHasClass(className) { return "contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' " + className +" ')"; } addEventListener(root, 'mouseover', function (e) { if ('' != refStyle.innerHTML) { refStyle.innerHTML = ''; } }); a('mouseover', function (a, e, c) { if (c) { e.target.style.cursor = "pointer"; } else if (a = idRx.exec(a.className)) { try { refStyle.innerHTML = 'pre.sf-dump .'+a[0]+'{background-color: #B729D9; color: #FFF !important; border-radius: 2px}'; } catch (e) { } } }); a('click', function (a, e, c) { if (/\bsf-dump-toggle\b/.test(a.className)) { e.preventDefault(); if (!toggle(a, isCtrlKey(e))) { var r = doc.getElementById(a.getAttribute('href').substr(1)), s = r.previousSibling, f = r.parentNode, t = a.parentNode; t.replaceChild(r, a); f.replaceChild(a, s); t.insertBefore(s, r); f = f.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); t = t.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); if (f && t && f[0] !== t[0]) { r.innerHTML = r.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('^'+f[0].replace(rxEsc, '\\$1'), 'mg'), t[0]); } if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(r.className)) { toggle(s, isCtrlKey(e)); } } if (c) { } else if (doc.getSelection) { try { doc.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); } catch (e) { doc.getSelection().empty(); } } else { doc.selection.empty(); } } else if (/\bsf-dump-str-toggle\b/.test(a.className)) { e.preventDefault(); e = a.parentNode.parentNode; e.className = e.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-str-(expand|collapse)\b/, a.parentNode.className); } }); elt = root.getElementsByTagName('SAMP'); len = elt.length; i = 0; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); len = t.length; for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) { elt = t[i]; if ('SAMP' == elt.tagName) { a = elt.previousSibling || {}; if ('A' != a.tagName) { a = doc.createElement('A'); a.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; elt.parentNode.insertBefore(a, elt); } else { a.innerHTML += ' '; } a.title = (a.title ? a.title+'\n[' : '[')+keyHint+'+click] Expand all children'; a.innerHTML += '<span>&#9660;</span>'; a.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; x = 1; if ('sf-dump' != elt.parentNode.className) { x += elt.parentNode.getAttribute('data-depth')/1; } elt.setAttribute('data-depth', x); var className = elt.className; elt.className = 'sf-dump-expanded'; if (className ? 'sf-dump-expanded' !== className : (x > options.maxDepth)) { toggle(a); } } else if (/\bsf-dump-ref\b/.test(elt.className) && (a = elt.getAttribute('href'))) { a = a.substr(1); elt.className += ' '+a; if (/[\[{]$/.test(elt.previousSibling.nodeValue)) { a = a != elt.nextSibling.id && doc.getElementById(a); try { s = a.nextSibling; elt.appendChild(a); s.parentNode.insertBefore(a, s); if (/^[@#]/.test(elt.innerHTML)) { elt.innerHTML += ' <span>&#9654;</span>'; } else { elt.innerHTML = '<span>&#9654;</span>'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } elt.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; } catch (e) { if ('&' == elt.innerHTML.charAt(0)) { elt.innerHTML = '&hellip;'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } } } } } if (doc.evaluate && Array.from && root.children.length > 1) { root.setAttribute('tabindex', 0); SearchState = function () { this.nodes = []; this.idx = 0; }; SearchState.prototype = { next: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return this.current(); } this.idx = this.idx < (this.nodes.length - 1) ? this.idx + 1 : 0; return this.current(); }, previous: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return this.current(); } this.idx = this.idx > 0 ? this.idx - 1 : (this.nodes.length - 1); return this.current(); }, isEmpty: function () { return 0 === this.count(); }, current: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return null; } return this.nodes[this.idx]; }, reset: function () { this.nodes = []; this.idx = 0; }, count: function () { return this.nodes.length; }, }; function showCurrent(state) { var currentNode = state.current(), currentRect, searchRect; if (currentNode) { reveal(currentNode); highlight(root, currentNode, state.nodes); if ('scrollIntoView' in currentNode) { currentNode.scrollIntoView(true); currentRect = currentNode.getBoundingClientRect(); searchRect = search.getBoundingClientRect(); if (currentRect.top < (searchRect.top + searchRect.height)) { window.scrollBy(0, -(searchRect.top + searchRect.height + 5)); } } } counter.textContent = (state.isEmpty() ? 0 : state.idx + 1) + ' of ' + state.count(); } var search = doc.createElement('div'); search.className = 'sf-dump-search-wrapper sf-dump-search-hidden'; search.innerHTML = ' <input type="text" class="sf-dump-search-input"> <span class="sf-dump-search-count">0 of 0<\/span> <button type="button" class="sf-dump-search-input-previous" tabindex="-1"> <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1683 1331l-166 165q-19 19-45 19t-45-19L896 965l-531 531q-19 19-45 19t-45-19l-166-165q-19-19-19-45.5t19-45.5l742-741q19-19 45-19t45 19l742 741q19 19 19 45.5t-19 45.5z"\/><\/svg> <\/button> <button type="button" class="sf-dump-search-input-next" tabindex="-1"> <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1683 808l-742 741q-19 19-45 19t-45-19L109 808q-19-19-19-45.5t19-45.5l166-165q19-19 45-19t45 19l531 531 531-531q19-19 45-19t45 19l166 165q19 19 19 45.5t-19 45.5z"\/><\/svg> <\/button> '; root.insertBefore(search, root.firstChild); var state = new SearchState(); var searchInput = search.querySelector('.sf-dump-search-input'); var counter = search.querySelector('.sf-dump-search-count'); var searchInputTimer = 0; var previousSearchQuery = ''; addEventListener(searchInput, 'keyup', function (e) { var searchQuery = e.target.value; /* Don't perform anything if the pressed key didn't change the query */ if (searchQuery === previousSearchQuery) { return; } previousSearchQuery = searchQuery; clearTimeout(searchInputTimer); searchInputTimer = setTimeout(function () { state.reset(); collapseAll(root); resetHighlightedNodes(root); if ('' === searchQuery) { counter.textContent = '0 of 0'; return; } var classMatches = [ "sf-dump-str", "sf-dump-key", "sf-dump-public", "sf-dump-protected", "sf-dump-private", ].map(xpathHasClass).join(' or '); var xpathResult = doc.evaluate('.//span[' + classMatches + '][contains(translate(child::text(), ' + xpathString(searchQuery.toUpperCase()) + ', ' + xpathString(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) + '), ' + xpathString(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) + ')]', root, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null); while (node = xpathResult.iterateNext()) state.nodes.push(node); showCurrent(state); }, 400); }); Array.from(search.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-search-input-next, .sf-dump-search-input-previous')).forEach(function (btn) { addEventListener(btn, 'click', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); -1 !== e.target.className.indexOf('next') ? state.next() : state.previous(); searchInput.focus(); collapseAll(root); showCurrent(state); }) }); addEventListener(root, 'keydown', function (e) { var isSearchActive = !/\bsf-dump-search-hidden\b/.test(search.className); if ((114 === e.keyCode && !isSearchActive) || (isCtrlKey(e) && 70 === e.keyCode)) { /* F3 or CMD/CTRL + F */ e.preventDefault(); search.className = search.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-search-hidden\b/, ''); searchInput.focus(); } else if (isSearchActive) { if (27 === e.keyCode) { /* ESC key */ search.className += ' sf-dump-search-hidden'; e.preventDefault(); resetHighlightedNodes(root); searchInput.value = ''; } else if ( (isCtrlKey(e) && 71 === e.keyCode) /* CMD/CTRL + G */ || 13 === e.keyCode /* Enter */ || 114 === e.keyCode /* F3 */ ) { e.preventDefault(); e.shiftKey ? state.previous() : state.next(); collapseAll(root); showCurrent(state); } } }); } if (0 >= options.maxStringLength) { return; } try { elt = root.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-str'); len = elt.length; i = 0; t = []; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); len = t.length; for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) { elt = t[i]; s = elt.innerText || elt.textContent; x = s.length - options.maxStringLength; if (0 < x) { h = elt.innerHTML; elt[elt.innerText ? 'innerText' : 'textContent'] = s.substring(0, options.maxStringLength); elt.className += ' sf-dump-str-collapse'; elt.innerHTML = '<span class=sf-dump-str-collapse>'+h+'<a class="sf-dump-ref sf-dump-str-toggle" title="Collapse"> &#9664;</a></span>'+ '<span class=sf-dump-str-expand>'+elt.innerHTML+'<a class="sf-dump-ref sf-dump-str-toggle" title="'+x+' remaining characters"> &#9654;</a></span>'; } } } catch (e) { } }; })(document); </script><style> pre.sf-dump { display: block; white-space: pre; padding: 5px; overflow: initial !important; } pre.sf-dump:after { content: ""; visibility: hidden; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; } pre.sf-dump span { display: inline; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-compact { display: none; } pre.sf-dump abbr { text-decoration: none; border: none; cursor: help; } pre.sf-dump a { text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; border: 0; outline: none; color: inherit; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ellipsis { display: inline-block; overflow: visible; text-overflow: ellipsis; max-width: 5em; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: top; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ellipsis+.sf-dump-ellipsis { max-width: none; } pre.sf-dump code { display:inline; padding:0; background:none; } .sf-dump-str-collapse .sf-dump-str-collapse { display: none; } .sf-dump-str-expand .sf-dump-str-expand { display: none; } .sf-dump-public.sf-dump-highlight, .sf-dump-protected.sf-dump-highlight, .sf-dump-private.sf-dump-highlight, .sf-dump-str.sf-dump-highlight, .sf-dump-key.sf-dump-highlight { background: rgba(111, 172, 204, 0.3); border: 1px solid #7DA0B1; border-radius: 3px; } .sf-dump-public.sf-dump-highlight-active, .sf-dump-protected.sf-dump-highlight-active, .sf-dump-private.sf-dump-highlight-active, .sf-dump-str.sf-dump-highlight-active, .sf-dump-key.sf-dump-highlight-active { background: rgba(253, 175, 0, 0.4); border: 1px solid #ffa500; border-radius: 3px; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-hidden { display: none !important; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper { font-size: 0; white-space: nowrap; margin-bottom: 5px; display: flex; position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky; top: 5px; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > * { vertical-align: top; box-sizing: border-box; height: 21px; font-weight: normal; border-radius: 0; background: #FFF; color: #757575; border: 1px solid #BBB; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > input.sf-dump-search-input { padding: 3px; height: 21px; font-size: 12px; border-right: none; border-top-left-radius: 3px; border-bottom-left-radius: 3px; color: #000; min-width: 15px; width: 100%; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-input-next, pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-input-previous { background: #F2F2F2; outline: none; border-left: none; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-input-next { border-top-right-radius: 3px; border-bottom-right-radius: 3px; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-input-next > svg, pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-input-previous > svg { pointer-events: none; width: 12px; height: 12px; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-count { display: inline-block; padding: 0 5px; margin: 0; border-left: none; line-height: 21px; font-size: 12px; }pre.sf-dump, pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-default{background-color:#18171B; color:#FF8400; line-height:1.2em; font:12px Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, monospace; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap; position:relative; z-index:99999; word-break: break-all}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-num{font-weight:bold; color:#1299DA}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-const{font-weight:bold}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-str{font-weight:bold; color:#56DB3A}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-note{color:#1299DA}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ref{color:#A0A0A0}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-public{color:#FFFFFF}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-protected{color:#FFFFFF}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-private{color:#FFFFFF}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-meta{color:#B729D9}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-key{color:#56DB3A}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-index{color:#1299DA}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ellipsis{color:#FF8400}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ns{user-select:none;}</style><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-703860600 data-indent-pad="  "><span class=sf-dump-note>array:1</span> [<samp>
```

"com-name" => null
]
Sfdump("sf-dump-703860600")

response i'm getting

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you share any of the code you are currently struggling with?

Comment: possible duplicate :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447435/ajax-upload-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you can see how to image upload in below link.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('section', 'general');
formData.append('action', 'previewImg');
// Attach file
formData.append('image', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]); 

/** For multiple file upload in different field **/

formData.append('image_input1', $('#image_input1')[0].files[0]);      
formData.append('image_input2', $('#image_input2')[0].files[0]);      

/** For multiple file upload in same field **/ 

let files = $('input[type=file]')[0];
for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
   formData.append('image['+i+']', files[i]);
}
```

[for more information click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: yeah this is showing image in preview but return the same script error too how to fix it??

Comment: You can checked the below link? 
                                                https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload

Comment: what if i sending image from two other inputs how will i receive in controller ??

Comment: Please see the updated code here are example for multiple file upload in same field and file upload in two different field.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH BUT BRO I HAVE ASKED THAT HOW will i receive this parameter in controller right now i'm doing this 
if($file=$request->file('image')){

                $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
                $path=$file->move('images',$name);
and then update the column with path but if i will send two inputs value then how will i magae in if condition

Answer (score 0):

dev,
Welcome to StackOverflow. Although the people in the comment section are right you should also post the code but as I have also suffered the same problem. I can understand. I am posting the sample code for the same hope it helps.

```
    let featuredImage = $('#featured-image');
    if (!typeof (featuredImage.get(0).files[0]) === "undefined") {
        formData.append('featured-image', featuredImage.get(0).files[0]);
    }

    let featuredImage2 = $('#featured-image-2');
    if (!typeof (featuredImage2.get(0).files[0]) === "undefined") {
        formData.append('featured-image-2', featuredImage2.get(0).files[0]);
    }
```

now use this formData in your ajax call. you will also get file. you can also add other form fields before the call.

In Controller:

```
if ($request->hasFile('featured-image')) {
    $request = $this->moveFeaturedImage($request);
}

/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Request
 */
private function moveFeaturedImage(Request $request)
{
    $image = $request->file('featured-image');
    $imageName = createNewImageName($image);
    $image->move(
        public_path(POST_IMAGE_DIR),
        $imageName
    );

    $request->merge([
        'featured_image' => $imageName
    ]);

    return $request;
}
```

I guess its quite explainatry now ?

Comment: what if i sending image from two other inputs how will i receive in controller ??

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH BUT BRO I HAVE ASKED THAT HOW will i receive this parameter in controller right now i'm doing this 
if($file=$request->file('image')){

                $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
                $path=$file->move('images',$name);
and then update the column with path but if i will send two inputs value then how will i magae in if condition

Comment: if you sand image along with two other input then you can manage by checking ` 
  $path = "";  if($request->hasFile('image')) {  $file=$request->file('image');  $name=$file->getClientOriginalName(); $path=$file->move('images',$name) }  $input1 = $request->get('input1'); $input2 = $request->get('input2');` and then  update it to database