# Upload image without refreshing/reloading the page in Flask

Tags: html, flask

I have one HTML form through which the user can upload an image but I don't want the to reload or refresh after the form submission.
Here's my HTML form:

```
   <html>  
    <head>  
        <title>upload</title>  
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <form action = "/success" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
            <input type="file" name="file" />  
            <input type = "submit" value="Upload">  
        </form>  
    </body>  
    </html>
```

And here's my flask app:

```
from flask import *  
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os
import skimage
import os.path
from os import path
from PIL import Image
import random
import imageio

app = Flask(__name__)  
       
UPLOAD_FOLDER = './flask app/uploads'

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
 
@app.route('/')  
def upload():  
    return render_template("index.html")  
 
@app.route('/success', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])  
def success():  
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        model = load_model()
        f = request.files['file']
        filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        print(filename)
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename))
        image = skimage.io.imread(UPLOAD_FOLDER+'/'+filename)
        results = model.detect([image], verbose=1)
        r = results[0]
        #visualize.display_instances(image, r['rois'], r['masks'], r['class_ids'], r['scores'])
        path, dirs, files = next(os.walk(UPLOAD_FOLDER))
        file_count = len(files)
        image_name = 'segmented_image'+str(file_count)+'.jpg'
        class_names = ['BG', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
        n = random.randint(0,100)
        folder_name = '/segmentation'+str(n)
        os.chdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER)
        dir_name = UPLOAD_FOLDER + folder_name
        os.mkdir(dir_name)
        os.chdir(dir_name)
        visualize.save_image(image, image_name, r['rois'], r['masks'], r['class_ids'], r['scores'], class_names=class_names, save_dir=dir_name)
        for i in range(r['rois'].shape[0]):
            n = random.randint(0, 100)
            img = image[r['rois'][i][0]:r['rois'][i][2], r['rois'][i][1]:r['rois'][i][3]]
            fname = 'seg'+ str(n)+'.jpg'
            imageio.imwrite(fname, img)
        return render_template("index.html", name = f.filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app.run(debug = True)
```

The uploaded image is saved successfully but the HTML page reloads which I don't want. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ajax Upload image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447435/ajax-upload-image)

Comment: As mentioned, you need to use Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called `upload.js` and use this code snippet:

```js
//upload.js
(function() {
    $('#Upload').click(function(){
        var fd = new FormData($('#file')[0]);
        fd.stopPropogation();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/success',
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('Success!');
            },
        });
    });
});
```

```html
   <html>  
    <head>  
        <title>upload</title>
        <script src="upload.js"></script>
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />  
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="Upload">  
        </form>  
    </body>  
    </html>
```

You can use the same server code that you need.