# How to upload image on server using ajax jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Actually I'm trying to upload a image on server using ajax jquery?

My Code:-

```js
$(function(){
$('#uploadFile').submit(function(){
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);
  
  $.ajax({
       url : 'upload.php',
       type : 'POST',
       data : formData,
       success : function(data) {
           console.log(data);
           alert(data);
       }
});
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="uploadFile">
<input type="file" id="file" />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Thankyou for your efforts!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: You can refer [ajax upload image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447435/ajax-upload-image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
$('#uploadFile').submit(function(){
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
       url : 'upload.php',
       type : 'POST',
       data : formData,
       contentType: false, // You need to add this
       processData: false,// You need to add this also
       success : function(data) {
           console.log(data);
           alert(data);
       }
});
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="uploadFile">
<input type="file" id="file" />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Now Its working fine... Thanks @Hakim Singh